# I am looking for an accurate pictorial description of the so called Gokarna Mudra

Tags: rituals, devi-bhagavata-purana, mudra

From how to perform achamana [as found in the Devi Bhagavata Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk11ch16.htm):

> Firstly make the ordinary Âchaman three times, and, while inhaling, drink a little of the water of Âchaman, repeating “Om
>   Kes’avâya Svâhâ, Om Nârâyanâya Svâhâ, Om Mâdhavâya Svâhâ.” Then wash
>   your two hands, repeating “Om Gobindâya Namah, Om Visnave Namah.” Then
>   by the root of the thumb rub the lips repeating “Om Madhû sûdanâya
>   Namah, Om Trivikramâya Namah.” So rub the mouth, repeating “Om
>   Vâmamâya Namah, Om S’rîdharâya Namah.” Then sprinkle water on the left
>   hand, saying “Om Hrisîkes’âya Namah.” Sprinkle water on the legs,
>   saying “Om Padmanâbhâya Namah.” Sprinkle water on the head, saying “Om
>   Dâmodarâya Namah.” Touch the mouth with the three fingers of the right
>   hand, saying “Om Samkarsanâya Namah.” Touch the nostrils with the
>   thumb and forefinger saying “Om Vâsudevâya Namah, Om Pradyumnâya
>   Namah.” Touch the eyes with the thumb and ring-finger, saying “Om
>   Aniruddhâya Namah, Om Purusottamâya Namah.” Touch the ears with the
>   thumb and ringfinger saying “Om Adhoksajâya Namah, Om Nârasimhâya
>   Namah.” Touch the navel with the thumb and little finger saying “Om
>   Achyutâya Namah.” Touch the breast with the palm, saying “Om
>   Janârdanâya Namah.” Touch the head saying “Om Upendrâya Namah.” Touch
>   the roots of the two arms saying “Om Haraye Namah, Om Krisnâya Namah.”
>
> While sipping the Âchaman water on the right hand, touch the right hand with your left hand; otherwise; the water does not become pure.
>   **While doing Âchaman, make the palm and the fingers all united and close, of the form of a Gokarna (the ear of a cow) and spreading the
>   thumb and the little finger, drink the water of the measure of a
>   pea.** If a greater or less quantity be sipped, then that would amount
>   to drinking liquor.

Till date, i have found a variety of descriptions of this particular mudra called the Gokarna Mudra. Varoius websites provide different descriptions and one does not match with the other.

The latest picture i found is from [this page](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hindi/hinduism/hinduism-practices/hindu-temple/tirth):

> [image]

Now, this picture is not quite matching with textual description given in the above Purana passage.

So, I am looking for the accurate pictorial description of the so called Gokarna Mudra.

I will accept the answer provided the reference in it is from a website or a book which i consider as trustworthy and authentic.

I myself have books that discuss several mudras used in worship like Leliha, Galini, Ankusha, Grasa etc but none provide anything on the Gokarna mudra.

Comment: Usually the above Mudra is only used while performing  Achamana. And it makes sense because only in that position the water stays in your palm. As for the definition given I think the Mudra matches. Where do you find the difference?

Comment: @Surya Why the tip of thumb digging into the side of the base of tarjani? The textual description does not say anything like that. In the text we find that thumb and lil finger need to spread out but in the pic it is not so. Also why is the tarjani in a curved position? Actually i have a fair idea of how to do the mudra but i want a very precise description from some authentic book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an [Upasmriti called the ViswAmitra Smriti, composed by Rishi ViswAmitra](http://www.hinduonline.co/vedicreserve/smriti/upasmriti/vishvamitra_smirti.pdf), finally was able to get an accurate textual description of how to form this so called Gokarna Mudra. And, from this textual description it's quite easy to form the Mudra.

It's there in a verse found on pp 14 of that PDF (which is in Sanskrit only). I am simply transliterating the needed verse here along with providing a SS. The section, where this verse is found, is entirely dedicated to depicting the Achamana Vidhi:

> [image]
>
> Angulitraya samyuktam muktAngushtha kanishthakam |
>   GokarnAkritirityAhu brAhmakarma prakirtitam ||

"Angulitraya samyuktam" - So, the three fingers (angulitrayam), the index, the middle and the ring finger, must be attached/joined (samyuktam) with each other.

"muktAngushtha kanishthakam" - but the Angushtha (or the thumb) and the KanishthA (or the little finger) must be free (mukta) from the association of the three fingers mentioned above.

So, I now know how to form this Mudra and my problem has been solved.